# C# Networking, beginner to advanced

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am looking for a tutorial about advanced C# networking, especially about the server part. i want to create a server that can take 1000 connections at the same time. I have learn more about Sockets and TcpClient, but i also know about WCF and UDP. I want an example of server that can have 1000 connections, i have searched on the google about a server like this but i didn't found any or maybe i didn't realize it can take 1000 connections. Do you know some example, tutorial or something else that can help me understand better this technology?

Comment: I found plenty of good tutorial just by typing a your idea on google.
[here](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c+%23+networking+tutorial)

Comment: I had made a server that can work perfect with about 200 connections and it works almost ok, and if more users connects that the server "falls" and some user are disconnected from the server and the users witch connects after this cannot comunicate with server... something a didn't figure out why this happens

Answer (score 3):

Using the keywords from your question, I came up with:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketsincsharp.aspx

Try to create server that will handle 1 connection first,

then 2,

then 10,

then 1000.

From 'what are sockets' to 'I need server with 1000 connections' there is at least ONE year for you, but don't let that discourage you.